# Why does this PowerShell script fail to execute this external command properly?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

The following code will output the command string I wish to run:

```
[string] $SourceRepo="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Spyda\"
[string] $Repo="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BranchClone\"
[string] $revstring="--rev `"default`" --rev `"case 1234`""

Write-Output "hg clone $SourceRepo $Repo $revstring"
```

Which gives

```
hg clone C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Spyda\ C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BranchClone\ --rev "default" --rev "case 1234"
```

If I run that from a powershell prompt, it works, if I try to run the hg clone command from a script using this syntax, it fails:

```
hg clone $SourceRepo $Repo $revstring
```

Error given:

```
hg.exe : hg clone: option --rev default --rev case not recognized
At line:6 char:3
+ hg <<<<  clone $SourceRepo $Repo $revstring
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (hg clone: optio... not recognized:String) [], RemoteE 
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Invoke-Expression

```
$SourceRepo="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Spyda\"
$Repo="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BranchClone\"
$revstring="--rev `"default`" --rev `"case 1234`""

$cmdString = "hg clone $SourceRepo $Repo $revstring"

Invoke-Expression $cmdString
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the call operator (&) this way:

```
 & '.\hg' clone $SourceRepo $Repo $revstring
```

Answer (score 0):

Using EchoArgs.exe from the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/), we can see what arguments hg.exe is receiving:

```
PS> & ./EchoArgs.exe clone $SourceRepo $Repo $revstring
Arg 0 is <clone>
Arg 1 is <C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Spyda\>
Arg 2 is <C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BranchClone\>
Arg 3 is <--rev default --rev case>
Arg 4 is <1234>
```

What happens is that powershell resolves the call to a native application, so it automatically uses quotes to escape variable arguments containing spaces,  such as `$revstring`.

Instead of pre-quoting our arguments, we can take advantage of this escaping by simply building up an array of the distinct values we want to use:

```
PS> $hgArgs = @('clone',$SourceRepo,$Repo,'--rev','default','--rev','case 1234')
PS> & ./EchoArgs.exe $hgArgs
Arg 0 is <clone>
Arg 1 is <C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Spyda\>
Arg 2 is <C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BranchClone\>
Arg 3 is <--rev>
Arg 4 is <default>
Arg 5 is <--rev>
Arg 6 is <case 1234>
```